# Azure repos - notify PR reviewer only if build passed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

Say I configure branch policies: Build validation and minimum number of reviewers. Can I configure Azure DevOps in such a way that the reviewers will be notified that they need to review the pull request only after a successful build?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's an out-of-the-box solution for this. The closest thing I can think of is a subscription to the build completion done as a result of pull request validation with the successful status:

[image]

This kind of notification might be the heads-up type of alert you need. Note, however, that the notification won't contain the link to the pull request itself, so you would probably need to monitor the PR notifications anyway...